# Best way to store and construct member const array or strings

Tags: arrays, c++11, member

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class foo {
  const A arr;
  foo(B arg): arr(arg) { }
};
```

What is the most efficient choice for the types of `A` and `B`. I was thinking something like this,

```
class foo {
  const std::initializer_list<std::string> arr;
  foo(std::initializer_list<std::string> arg): arr(arg) { }
};
```

But I think this will copy-construct strings in `arr`. I'd like to be able to do this:

```
std::string str1("there"), str2("now");
foo bar({"hello",str1,std::move(str2)});
```

and have rvalue strings in the brackets moved into `arr`.

Should I use `std::initializer_list`, or `std::vector`, or something else?

Comment: Don't use an `initializer_list` as a member. `initializer_list` is **not** a container, it doesn't manage storage, it only refers to an externally allocated array. It's for _initializing_ things, not for storing things. The clue is in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Define `arr` as `std::vector<std::string>`, and the ctor's argument as `std::initializer_list<std::string>`, mostly what you have guessed.

Comment: Will `str2` in my usage example be moved with this implementation?